# MySQL Where clause refinement IF join exists

Tags: mysql

I have a query similar to below.  I want to add a criteria for RevisionBlast IF the row exists for that record.

```
select count(*)
from RevisionRun rr 
inner join RevisionForm rf on rf.id = rr.revisionformid
left outer join RevisionBlast rb on rb.RevisionRunId = rf.id
where rr.IsDeleted = 0 
  and rf.IsDeleted = 0;
```

I was thinking something similar to below.  I think this works but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient/performant way to handle this.  I'm assuming this is a pretty common thing so I just wanted to make sure I'm doing this right.

```
select count(*)
from RevisionRun rr 
inner join RevisionForm rf on rf.id = rr.revisionformid
left outer join RevisionBlast rb on rb.RevisionRunId = rf.id
where rr.IsDeleted = 0 
  and rf.IsDeleted = 0 
  and (IF(rb.IsDeleted is null or rb.IsDeleted = 0, 1, 0) = 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
select count(*)
from RevisionRun rr 
inner join RevisionForm rf on rf.id = rr.revisionformid
left outer join RevisionBlast rb on rb.RevisionRunId = rf.id
                                and rb.IsDeleted = 0
where rr.IsDeleted = 0 
  and rf.IsDeleted = 0;
```

That is, put the extra condition into the join condition for `rb`. Then only those rows in `rb` that match the extra condition will satisfy the join.

A compound index on `RrevisionBlast(RevisionRunId,IsDeleted)` will help optimize the join.